# Using preg_match on a multidimensional array to return key values arrays

Tags: php, foreach, preg-match, key-value

I have an array that is structured as such:

```
$data = array(
    "abc"=>array(
            "label" => "abc",
            "value" => "def",
            "type" => "ghi",
            "desc" => "jkl",
            ),
    "def"=>array(
            "label" => "mno",
            "value" => "qrs",
            "type" => "tuv",
            "desc" => "wxyz",
            ),
    );
```

I want to use preg_match with a foreach loop to perform a search on the arrays contained in $data and return the nested arrays of key value pairs.

Comment: What is your question? It is possible what you describe, are you asking for a better solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?php
$data = array(
    "abc"=>array(
            "label" => "abc",
            "value" => "def",
            "type" => "ghi",
            "desc" => "jkl",
            ),
    "def"=>array(
            "label" => "mno",
            "value" => "qrs",
            "type" => "tuv",
            "desc" => "wxyz",
            ),
    );

$matches = array();
$pattern = "/a/i";  //contains an 'a'
//loop through the data
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    //loop through each key under data sub array
    foreach($value as $key2=>$value2){
        //check for match.
        if(preg_match($pattern, $value2)){
            //add to matches array.
            $matches[$key]=$value;
            //match found, so break from foreach
            break;
        }
    }
}
echo '<pre>'.print_r($matches, true).'</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 16):

for the googlers out there here's the better code

```
$data = <as above>
$pattern = "/whatever/";

$matches = array_filter($data, function($a) use($pattern)  {
    return preg_grep($pattern, $a);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I had never used either array_filter or preg_grep.  * *mumbles* * I'm off to (re)write some code now...

Comment: This does the same as the accepted answer. The only difference I can see with the accepted answer is the option to break out of the loop at any time. Both answers returns the whole nested array that has a matching value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP 5.5 and are viewing this question in 2015, this might be a more simple answer:

```
$elements= array_column($array, 1); //Where 1 is the name of the column or the index
$foundElements = preg_grep("/regex/i", $elements);
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers above worked on my case, so I'll leave my solution here maybe it can be useful to someone

```
function multidimensionalArrayScan($arr, $pattern, &$result = []) : Array
    {

        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

            if (is_array($arr[$key])) {
                self::multidimensionalArrayScan($arr[$key], $pattern, $result);
                continue;
            }

            $match  = preg_match($pattern, $value);
            if (!empty($match))
                $result[$key] = $value;
        }

        return $result;
    }

$data = <as above>
$pattern = "/whatever/";
multidimensionalArrayScan($data, $pattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$c=['abccd','123','12qw']; // where u'll search
$a = Array('/a/i', '/\d/i', '/\d+\w/i'); // what is
$b = array_map(function($a,$c){return (preg_match_all($a,$c,$m))? ($m[0][0]) : '';}, $a,$c);
print_r($b);
```

Comment: Somebody dares to explain?

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_grep('/needle/iu', array_column($haystack, "columnName", "keyName" ) );
```

Case-insensitive unicode grep on column `columnName` in array `$haystack`

Answer (score 0):

preg_match_all returns the rows that match a pattern with a specific column name.

```
$pattern = "/REDUCTION/i";
$reductions = array_filter($data, function($a) use($pattern)  {
    return preg_match_all($pattern, $a['budget']);
});
```