# loop through an array and apply preg_match

Tags: php

i need to walk through an multidimensional array and and check ONLY the title if not start with alphabetic , as the follow :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [letter] =>  
            [id] => 176
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [letter] => "
            [id] => 175
        )
.....etc
```

so i need to check only letter if not start with a-zA-z , i have try do that , but still have something missing  ,,

```
$notMatch = array();
foreach ($data as $value) {
    foreach ($value as $item['title']=>$d) {

       if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]$/',$d)){
           $notMatch[]=$d;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below URL i think it is very help full to you.

**Update:**

[Using preg_match on a multidimensional array to return key values arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281700/using-preg-match-on-a-multidimensional-array-to-return-key-values-arrays)

**Try it**

```
<?php
$data = array(
    "abc"=>array(
            "label" => "abc",
            "value" => "def",
            "type" => "ghi",
            "desc" => "jkl",
            ),
    "def"=>array(
            "label" => "mno",
            "value" => "qrs",
            "type" => "tuv",
            "desc" => "wxyz",
            ),
    );

$matches = array();
$pattern = "/a/i";  //contains an 'a'
//loop through the data
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    //loop through each key under data sub array
    foreach($value as $key2=>$value2){
        //check for match.
        if(preg_match($pattern, $value2)){
            //add to matches array.
            $matches[$key]=$value;
            //match found, so break from foreach
            break;
        }
    }
}
echo '<pre>'.print_r($matches, true).'</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: this in case of pattern in an array , i have different case , i have fixed pattern (/^[a-zA-Z]$/) , which i want to applay in multidimensional array , which have item ['title','id'] , problem is how can apply the pattern for only the title , please try read my question again

Comment: I have update my Answer currently please take a look. see this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281700/using-preg-match-on-a-multidimensional-array-to-return-key-values-arrays

Answer (score 1):

I removed one foreach loop and changed your preg_match pattern, removed the start of string/line and end of string/line anchors.

This is how I did it:

```
// I'm assuming your data array looks something like this:
$data = array(array('title'=>'fjsdoijsdiojsd', 'id'=>3),
                    array('title'=>'oijijsd', 'id'=>5),
                    array('title'=>'09234032', 'id'=>3));

$notMatch = array();
foreach ($data as $value) {
   if(!preg_match('/([a-zA-Z]).*/',$value['title'])){
       $notMatch[]=$value['title'];
       echo 'notmatch! ' . $value['title'];
   }
}
```

However, it's quite possible that someone with more regex experience can get you a better pattern. :)

http://codepad.viper-7.com/dvUQoW